# New to web scraping in R - how to use the rvest package to scrape IMDB movie data?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm brand new to web scraping in R and not very familiar with HTML code. I'm trying to scrape data from the top 50 IMDB movies at https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?sort=user_rating,desc&groups=top_250. I know to use *read_html* which gives me an XML object, and then I know I need to use *html_nodes* to extract the movie titles. But because I'm not very familiar with html, I'm struggling to figure out what those nodes are named. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
website <- "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?sort=user_rating,asc&groups=top_250"
page <- read_html(website)
movie_titles <- page %>%
  html_nodes("node_name_here") %>%
  html_text()
```

Comment: In addition to answers here you might want to check some external resources as well, e.g. rvest/scraping chapter of r4ds happens to use IMDB for one of its examples and also covers some html basics - https://r4ds.hadley.nz/webscraping

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Inspect option when you right click on the webpage to get the correct node. Then you need to find the node that has the information that you need.

[image]

There are multiple options but I have used `a` and `h3` tags along with it's class to get correct values.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
website <- "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?sort=user_rating,desc&groups=top_250"

page <- read_html(website)
movie_titles <- page %>%
  html_nodes("a h3.ipc-title__text") %>%
  html_text() 

movie_titles 

movie_titles
# [1] "1. The Shawshank Redemption"                         
# [2] "2. 12th Fail"                                        
# [3] "3. The Godfather"                                    
# [4] "4. The Dark Knight"                                  
# [5] "5. The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King"    
# [6] "6. Schindler's List"                                 
# [7] "7. The Godfather Part II"                            
# [8] "8. 12 Angry Men"                                     
# [9] "9. The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring"
#...
#...
#[47] "47. American History X"                              
#[48] "48. The Pianist"                                     
#[49] "49. Intouchables"                                    
#[50] "50. Casablanca"
```

You can do some data cleaning to remove numbers and get only movie names from it.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about the inspect option... the HTML does look a lot cleaner in the inspect window. How did you track down the "ipc-title_text" within that? For example, another thing I want to scrape is the movie rating, and just searching for "rating" I don't see anything in there.

Comment: "ipc-title_text" is the class of `h3` tag which is denoted with a `.` in `html_nodes`. For rating, you can use something like `html_nodes("span .ratingGroup--imdb-rating")`

Comment: You can use Selector Gadget in Chrome to point on specific element on webpage and it will show you the corresponding HTML for it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach here would be to use regex.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

website <- "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?sort=user_rating,asc&groups=top_250"

page <- read_html(website)
```

If we search for the movie titles in this returned list, we can see that they always occur after `\"originalTitleText\":\"` and before another `\.` For example, `\"originalTitleText\":\"Groundhog Day\`.

We can convert the list to a string, then use regex based on the above pattern to extract the movie titles.

```
collapsed_page <- paste(page, collapse = " ")

pattern <- '(?<=\\"originalTitleText\\":\\")[^\\"]+'

matches <- regmatches(collapsed_page, gregexpr(pattern, collapsed_page, perl=TRUE))
```

If you want these movies as a dataframe, you could then do:

```
df <- data.frame(match = unlist(matches))
```

Comment: _Abandon all hope ye who enter here_. Regex on HTML is fraught with many perils. While one may solve some smaller issues with HTML parsing/scraping using regex, in general **it is the wrong tool**. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3358272 (and https://i.imgur.com/gOPS2.png, in case the answer is edited again).

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the info/context. I'm still learning too so I wasn't aware of this issue. The linked answer is funny, this was helpful to read also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: That's a good link. Yes, the answer I linked seems "serious" enough until one starts to realize the absurdity of the character-set ... but it's not wrong :-)